# Java awt.print with Dot-matrix Printer

Tags: java, awt

I use awt.print to write a print program which works well for a network connected Ink-jet Printer. When I run the program on a USB Dot-matrix Printer, it seems doesn't work.(the program can recognizes the printer) Can anyone tell me why.
Here is some codesnip:

```
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page)
        throws PrinterException {
    /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
    if (page > 0)  return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setPaint(Color.black);

    drawPage(g2, page);
    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
}

public void drawPage(Graphics2D g2, int page) {
    Font font1 = new Font("宋体", Font.BOLD, 14);
    g2.setFont(font1);
    g2.drawString(printStr1, 10.0, 10.0); 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to take a look at [TextPrinter](http://www.java4less.com/textprinter/Documentation.html) since you are working with a dot matrix printer.

Anyway it *should* work with the snippet you got there, my guess is maybe an issue with the font, try printing some other text in a western font.